# Using a function to create a data-frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks like:

```
            dept          ratio higher  lower
      date  
01/01/1979     B    0.522576565      2      1
01/01/1979     A    0.940614079      2      2
01/01/1979     C    0.873957946      0      1
01/01/1979     B    0.087828824      0      2
01/01/1979     A    0.39754345       1      2
01/01/1979     A    0.475491609      1      2
01/01/1979     B    0.140605283      0      2
01/01/1979     A    0.071007362      0      2
01/01/1979     B    0.480720923      2      2
01/01/1979     A    0.673142643      1      2
01/01/1979     C    0.73554271       0      0
```

I would like to create a new column called `compared` where for each row I would like to count the number of values in the `dept` column that match the row `dept` value minus 1.  If the count is greater or equal to 1 then I would like returned to the `compared` column the solution to the following:

```
`compared` row value = (higher - lower) / count of dept column which matches the dept row value - 1
```

If the count of departments is 0 then 0 would be returned to the compared column.

For example, for the first row in `df` the `dept` value is B. There are 4 values of B in the `dept` column.  4-1  is greater than 1.  Therefore in the new `compared` column I would like entered the `higher` column value (2) minus the `lower` column value (1) which equals 1 divided by 4-1

or

```
(2-1)/(4-1) = 0.333333333
```

so my desired output would look like:

```
            dept          ratio higher  lower      compared
date    
01/01/1979     B    0.522576565      2      1   0.333333333
01/01/1979     A    0.940614079      2      2   0.000000000
01/01/1979     C    0.873957946      0      1  -1.000000000
01/01/1979     B    0.087828824      0      2  -0.666666667
01/01/1979     A    0.39754345       1      2  -0.250000000
01/01/1979     A    0.475491609      1      2  -0.250000000
01/01/1979     B    0.140605283      0      2  -0.666666667
01/01/1979     A    0.071007362      0      2  -0.500000000
01/01/1979     B    0.480720923      2      2   0.000000000
01/01/1979     A    0.673142643      1      2  -0.250000000
01/01/1979     C    0.73554271       0      0   0.000000000
```

I have some code but it's really slow:

```
    minDept=1
    for staticidx, row in df.iterrows():
        dept = row['dept']
        deptCount = deptPivot.loc[dept, "date"] # if error then zero
        myLongs= df.loc[staticidx, "higher"]
        myShorts= df.loc[staticidx, "lower"]

        if deptCount > minDept:

           df.loc[staticidx, "compared"] = (higher- lower)/(deptCount-1)

        else:
           df.loc[staticidx, "compared"] = 0
```

Is there a faster way that I can do this?

Comment: Unless there is a good reason not to do so, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather straight-forward:

```
counts = df.groupby('dept')['dept'].transform('count')-1

df['compared'] = (df['higher']-df['lower'])/counts

# to avoid possible division by zero warning
# also to match `counts>0` condition
# use this instead
# df.loc[counts>0,'compared'] = df['higher'].sub(df['lower']).loc[counts>0]/counts[counts>0]
```

Output:

```
           dept     ratio  higher  lower  compared
date                                              
01/01/1979    B  0.522577       2      1  0.333333
01/01/1979    A  0.940614       2      2  0.000000
01/01/1979    C  0.873958       0      1 -1.000000
01/01/1979    B  0.087829       0      2 -0.666667
01/01/1979    A  0.397543       1      2 -0.250000
01/01/1979    A  0.475492       1      2 -0.250000
01/01/1979    B  0.140605       0      2 -0.666667
01/01/1979    A  0.071007       0      2 -0.500000
01/01/1979    B  0.480721       2      2  0.000000
01/01/1979    A  0.673143       1      2 -0.250000
01/01/1979    C  0.735543       0      0  0.000000
```